# spark to hive data types

Tags: apache-spark, hive, type-conversion, hiveql

is there a way, how to convert an input string field into orc table with column specified as varchar(xx) in sparksql select query? Or I have to use some workaroud? I'm using Spark 1.6.

I found on Cloudera forum, Spark does not care about length, it saves the value as string with no size limit.

The table is inserted into Hive OK, but I'm little bit worried about data quality.

```
temp_table = sqlContext.table(ext)
df = temp_table.select(temp_dable.day.cast('string'))
```

I would like to see something like that :)))

```
 df = temp_table.select(temp_dable.day.cast('varchar(100)'))
```

Edit:

```
df.write.partitionBy(part).mode('overwrite').insertInto(int)
```

Table I'm inserting into is saved as an ORC file (the line above probably should have .format('orc')).

I found [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/48260/hive-string-vs-varchar-performance.html), that If I specify a column as a varchar(xx) type, than the input string will be cutoff to the xx length.

Thx

Comment: Did you get any results on this? I am stuck at the exact same case. Any help would be appreciated.